# Ruby on rails: rubygem error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I having a problem:

```
$ rake db:create
(in /Users/devinross14/myapp)
rake aborted!
RubyGem version error: rake-compiler(0.6.0 not ~> 0.5.0)

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For whatever version, you need version 0.5 or lower of rake-compiler, and you currently have version 0.6.0.  When installing gems, you can specify the version.

```
sudo gem install rake-compiler -v "=0.5.0"
```